# Change axis labels from months to years

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a dataset that shows too many labels in the axis.  When I display it as months, it is too crowded.  I want the change the labels to years, but leave the lines unchanged.

Here is some sample code to explain what I am trying.

```
library (ggplot2)
library (dplyr)
library (tidyr)

# create data
a = paste("m_",1:36,sep = "") # lables for 36 months of data
b = paste("c",1:6,sep = "")
mydata = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(36),6,36))
names(mydata) = a
mydata$cust = b
mydata = mydata[,c(ncol(mydata),1:(ncol(mydata)-1))] #move "cust" to 1st column

# plot data
p_data = mydata %>% gather(period,Qty,-cust)
p_data[, 2] <- factor(p_data[, 2], levels = unique(p_data[, 2])) # from Stackoverflow (thanks!)
pl=(ggplot(data=p_data,aes(x=period,y=Qty,group=cust,colour=cust)) +
    geom_line(size=.4))

# print plot
pl
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#Look at `?scale_x_discrete`, for example:

#Make x axis breaks and labels
xbrks <- c('m_1', 'm_13', 'm_25', 'm_36')
xlabs <- paste('Year', 1:length(xbrks))

# plot data
p_data = mydata %>% gather(period,Qty,-cust)
p_data[, 2] <- factor(p_data[, 2], levels = unique(p_data[, 2])) # from Stackoverflow (thanks!)
pl=(ggplot(data=p_data,aes(x=period, y=Qty,group=cust,colour=cust)) +
    geom_line(size=.4)) + scale_x_discrete(breaks=xbrks, labels=xlabs)

# print plot
pl
```

Comment: Actually, I use this for different sizes of dataframes, so the number of years changes.  Rather than specifically naming the xbrks, is there another way?